# Can't post to DB node with nginx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, server, lets-encrypt

Im making a website that's going to be hosted with my raspberry pi. I have set up Nginx with letsencrypt, everything is working except the post request. It worked with localhost, but not with Nginx. When I try to post to DB it never does that, it just times out. Here is the config for Nginx:

server {

```
    server_name bennjoe.ddns.net;


    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
    }



listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bennjoe.ddns.net/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bennjoe.ddns.net/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
```

}
server {

```
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;

if ($scheme != "https") {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }


if ($host = bennjoe.ddns.net) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


    server_name bennjoe.ddns.net;
    return 404;
```

}

Has this problem happened before? The post requests don't work with Nginx, it worked before, but when I added letsencrypt it didn't seem to work. But it works with localhost, so this seems to be something with Nginx. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Mongodb wasn't started on my server. I feel stupid